# Only turn of laptop screen, leave external monitors as is

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display

I have a new Dell Laptop with Win10,

- 2 external monitors connected with displayport via usb-c docking station.
- How can I turn of the laptop screen via script/ power button and the 2 monitors are still working
- The same result is already happening when closing the laptop.
- My laptop does not have a shortcut for only laptop screen of. It does have `fn + f8` which is the same as `win` + `p` and does not solve the issue.

TLDR; I want to ONLY toggle off and on the  laptop screen.

The current solutions I have tried turn of ALL Monitors.

Comment: Some laptops have the ability to do that with a fn key combination.

Comment: thank you. Ive updated my pos. My laptop does not have this key.

Comment: Take a look at these and see if any of them will work https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ways-turn-off-windows-10-laptop-screen/